# How close did Voldemort come to taking over the first time?

Tags: harry-potter, voldemort

During the events of book 7, we can pretty much see that Voldemort won, with the exception of the resistance in place. He ran the ministry, had his policies enforced, etc. How close did he come to winning the first time he was in power?